# Have a PATH repo supply a newer versions than a VCS repo

Tags: composer-php

For a while we deployed our local packages to a specific folder `packages.stable`and added that as a path repo. For testing purposes each developer has a copy of that machine and has an additional similar folder `packages.mine` were personal versions are stored (e.g. a new feature). Depending on the developer the folder `packages.mine` had newer or older versions compared to `packages.stable`, as well as some packages missing. As it was a local repo, we had the version attributein all composer.json files.

This allowed to `composer req my/package1:*@dev` and composer took the best alternative, either stable if my packages were old or missing, or mine if they were newer. This way no developer needed to care about all packages.

Now we wanted to move the stable folder packages to multiple VCS. Suddenly the overwrite is not working anymore, as `composer up` always ignores the local path repo `packages.mine` and takes "newest commit" from the VCS.

Is there a way to achieve the former scenario if stable is a VCS? Or is that some unpredicted behaviour bound to local path repos which only worked by chance?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed no problem at all if one uses a different prerelease suffix. `-dev` is a special reserved suffix and `dev-master`always points to some commit which is then set to `-dev` (dev-master might point to a branch, but still). That is actually the reason why `-dev123` is no valid composer version, also it is a valid semver. So avoiding`-dev` means ignoring the latest commit `dev-master`.

If the "local" code use an reserved suffix which is not `-dev`it works, e.g. `-alpha`. This allows the local code to have numbered suffixes like `-alpha123`as well. Adding a `composer req my/package1:*@alpha` creates the desired state where local path repo takes precedence over any VCS version.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability